# SQL Query with phpMyAdmin

Tags: mysql, sql, database

My table consists of 5 fields:

```
Submission ValueId  1 2 3 4 5
FormId  1 2 3 4 5
SubmissionId  22 or 23 or 24 
FieldName  fullname,Date,ville,
FieldValue 1 Paul  01/10/2013 Bern
```

Table I want to:

```
SELECT FormId, SubmissionId, FieldValue FROM qesnd_rsform_submission_values WHERE      FieldValue = Bern AND FormID='1' ORDER BY SubmissionId ASC"
```

With formid : 1
With FieldValue : Paul
With FieldValue : 01/10/2013
With FielValue : Bern

My problem how to make my request phpMyAdmin with multiple select?

Comment: a puzzle? share the `show create table qesnd_rsform_submission_values` output. What do you mean multiple select? selecting multiple records?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It looks like your data is a bit over-normalized, with a separate row for each field. I thnk the best way to access this data is by aggregation, assuming that field names are not repeated for any formid:

```
select formid, submissionId,
       max(case when fieldName = 'FullName' then fieldvalue end) as FullName,
       max(case when fieldName = 'Date' then fieldvalue end) as DateStr,
       max(case when fieldName = 'ville' then fieldValue end) as Ville
from t
where formid = 1
group by SubmissionId
```

If you want to select the information on a filter, then try:

```
select *
from (select formid, submissionId,
             max(case when fieldName = 'FullName' then fieldvalue end) as FullName,
             max(case when fieldName = 'Date' then fieldvalue end) as DateStr,
             max(case when fieldName = 'ville' then fieldValue end) as Ville
      from t
      group by SubmissionId
     ) t
 where formid = 1 and FullName = 'Paul' and DateStr = '01/10/2013' and Ville = 'Bern'
```